# Login Form focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a login and register page.

[image]

This is the form. Suppose if I am click on ABOUT US page and return to login page **(click back button)**, the content of this page showing like this..

[image]

My requirement is, If I am return to login page **(from ABOUT US)**, the label should be in the top of the Mail Id **(look in 1st image)**. Password is ok. Because we need to type again.

here is my code fiddle.. [fiddle.jshell.net/1nmmcj80/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/1nmmcj80/)

Comment: You want the email and password field to stay up if input exist?

Comment: @Cernodile, Yes. It is works for me.(In the fiddle it is not working). Actually, if we are trying to login a page, when the password is not correct, it will show an error. right? that time the email is still remain there. I need only the same thing. the email input field should stay up even the error is occured.

Answer (score 0):

According to your jsfiddle, `$` is not defined. It seems like you're trying to use jQuery, while it's not loaded. By loading jQuery your fiddle worked perfectly fine.

So the fix would be to load jQuery **before** your script.